# Supress ssh mail errors only

Tags: ssh, plesk

Hello I currently have a script that creates ssh tasks on the fly but want to be able to suppress only ones that have to do with email creation, for example if I try

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/mail -r test@domain.com
```

if the user does not exist I get

> An error occured during mailname removal: Mailname 'test@domain.com'
>   doesn't exists

or for that matter if I create an account, suppress the output.

Comment: I do not understand the relation between "a script that creates ssh tasks" and "[tasks that are related to] email creation". Could you try reformulating your question ?

Comment: And show the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `2>/dev/null` to the end the line which is responsible for mailbox creation and removal, e.g.:
Before:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/mail -r $var
```

After:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/mail -r $var 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thought this fixed it and while it works for most of the commands I'm having an issue with -u ... `/usr/local/psa/bin/mail -u test@domain.com -aliases add:test2 $var 2>/dev/null` still throws a response. @Elvis Plesky